# Does childism influence evolution of humans?

Tags: ethics, racism

Childism can be [defined](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childism) as follows :

> Childism can refer either to advocacy for empowering children as a
> subjugated group or to prejudice and/or discrimination against
> children or childlike qualities.[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childism) It can operate thus both as a
> positive term for a movement, like the term feminism, as well as a
> critical term to identify a phenomenon, like the term racism.

My question is : What do philosophers think about the influence of childism on the evolution of mankind ? Does the future belong to the kids or kid like qualities ? Given that so many kids died in Gaza Israel war , should childism be recognised like feminism ?

Comment: while it is wrong to think that children are deficient adults, it is also wrong to think that we need to free children from the tyranny of adults. hth

Comment: [SacrificialEquation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/43906/sacrificialequation) I don't think children will care about childishness. And it is the demonic children who represent infantilism as central and fanatical (Cult Childism). With the prolongation of human life, limbs age proportionally more slowly, but this does not mean that the biological development process becomes simpler. Infantilism is a concept of terror used to define children as ecological agents in its full sense, an attempt to adapt the behavior of single-celled and simple living things to the species.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean evolution in the biological sense, then childism is far too new of an idea to have had any noticeable impact on that. Although many animals, humans included, instinctively care about children, because doing so helps the species survive.

As for evolution in the more colloquial sense, people have advocated for the empowerment of children in various ways, such as advocating against corporal punishment, "bullying" (assault), and abuse, and advocating for freedom of religion, access to life-saving medical treatment, access to proper education, etc. I don't know that you can comment on how that influenced the "evolution of mankind", but it could certainly have improved the lives of a whole lot of children.

And the future certainly "belongs to the kids" in a practical sense, due to the passage of time and the mortality of humans. Kid-like qualities, on the other hand: you'll probably need to consider those qualities on an individual basis.

---

But as for the Gaza Israel war, many women and men are also dying. Children aren't being discriminated against (such that their empowerment is needed) if people are dying indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2):

On how youthful characters can help propel biological evolution, you may wish to check the concept of neoteny, which describes how new species can appear by retaining in adults traits previously seen only in the young. Neoteny is thought to have played a role in human evolution from apes.

On the ethical value of children vis a vis adults, I recommend the preface of The Little Prince by Saint-Ex.

Answer (score 0):

It's really nice question.

I think Childism can be path towards Evolution.

- Child

  ***Meaning***: A child is a young human being, typically one who has not yet reached the age of puberty or adulthood.
  ***Etymology***: The word "child" has Old English origins. It is derived from the Proto-Germanic word "kiltham" and is related to the Gothic word "kilþei" and Old High German "kilida," all of which mean "womb" or "uterus." The original sense of the word pertained to a fetus or an unborn or newly born child. Over time, its meaning evolved to refer to a young person.
  ***Type of Word***: "Child" is a noun. Specifically, it is a common noun as it refers to a general class of people rather than a particular individual.
- Evolution

  ***Meaning***: Evolution refers to the gradual development or change of living organisms over successive generations, often driven by natural selection, genetic variation, and environmental factors. It can also refer to broader processes of development, change, or growth in various fields.
  ***Etymology***: The word "evolution" comes from the Latin word "evolutio," meaning "an unrolling" or "a development." It was first used in a biological context by Charles Darwin in the 19th century.
  ***Type of Word:*** "Evolution" is a common noun.
- Have we undergone Holistic Evolution?

  1. Biological: Yes! We have come all the way from apes to modern humans.
  2. Intellectual: Yes! We have discovered subtle secrets of universe, we are just stepping into AI revolution
  3. Psychological: No(Perhaps)! The wars now are more dangerous than they were in stone age. Crimes are more heinous. Depression and anxiety have became prevalent. Religious Extremism is still present.

##### What is needed for psychological Evolution?

*Stupidity of old generation becomes tradition of new generation*
The brain which can look clearly without any prejudices, opinions, biases. A thinking which is free. A mind free of conditioning. A Liberal outlook, pure and pristine heart, is all needed for radical change a revolution.

##### Why Children?

Children have all above qualities essential for bringing about psychological Evolution. If they are kept free of conditioning of past generations and are given proper nourishment, a new generation will be born which will lead mankind to total revolution.

Childism, when taken in postive sense can generate wave of renaissance. Future belongs to Children.

Comment: welcome to the internet, it's kate, and those are *block quotes*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @prof_ghost yes I know,  I was just playing with them, it looks good to write that way.

Comment: @Junsui: We have clear standards & guidelines to support there being good quality answers on this site. See 'How to write a good answer' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer Answers that don't meet the standards risk them being deleted. I like a bit of etymology in an answer, & I don't think your answer is bad enough to downvote, never mind delete. But *"Stupidity of old generation becomes tradition of new generation"* verges on being a *deepity*. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deepity

Comment: @prof_ghost Text within bullet points should arguably be indented. (Who's Kate?)

Comment: oh my guess is that it's this person's wife (sorry, i'm insane lol) @NotThatGuy

Comment: @CriglCragl Much of society is based on unquestioned traditions that come from older generations, and their arguable "stupidity" (or rather their lack of knowledge, poor moral principles, a long game of [telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers), etc.). That realisation is a big part of modern skepticism.

Comment: @CriglCragl Gosh! Pardon if you took it as impudent statement or "deepity". But for me it's a "fact". In our land we had tradition that nearly half of the population was marginalized from mainstream of society till some 70 years ago and it is there in diluted form till today!!. They were not allowed to do farming, they fed upon carcasses of dead cattle, they were not allowed to drink water from common well, they needed to carry a pot tied to their necks to spit in and a broom tied to their waist so that they clean the impurity they caused. Isn't it stupidity of old .Time has come to accept it.

Comment: @Junsui: Obviously the Untouchable tradition is problematic. You may not know it was crucial to the British getting a foothold in India at a time when the Marathas were close to overpowering the Mughals. The strictures on Untouchables made a large pool of dissatisfied people the British were able to recruit as mercenaries. When you look in to cultural practices there is generally more going on than 'old people bad'. See eg 'Whence comes nihilism, the uncanniest of all guests?' https://aeon.co/ideas/whence-comes-nihilism-the-uncanniest-of-all-guests  esp intergenerational legibility, & metis